# HTML output differs between deployed and local

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In my `Person` model I got birthdate property:

```
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

In Edit view I got birth date input field displayed:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

On localhost it produces HTML:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth must be a date." data-val-required="Pole Date of Birth jest wymagane." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" value="2014-10-02">
```

and the value of the field is displayed in the browser after the page is loaded:
[image]

I published my application but the produced HTML is slightly different. It doesn't contain the word `valid` and the `value` format is different:`"2/5/2015"`  instead of `"2014-10-02"`.

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth must be a date." data-val-required="The Date of Birth field is required." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" value="2/5/2015">
```

This causes that the date is not displayed in the input field until I set it by datepicker.

[image]

I want it to behave the same way as locally deployed app.

I am based in Poland, The application was deployed to the myasp.net servers which I bet are in Anglo-Saxon country with different date format. Is this might be a problem?

Comment: I have had a problem like this which was caused by a file existing in my local workspace but I had not included it in the project, so would not be copied over to the remote server during deployment. It would work fine on localhost but after a deployment, it would not work.

Comment: i think you have a culture problem. The thread current culture on the server is different than the one of your local system, therefore the date format is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should *set your culture in your webProject manually*. By this the culture settings on the deployment server won't be applied.

**web.config**

```
<globalization uiCulture="pl" culture="pl-PL" />
```

see [MSDN - How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.140).aspx)

If you are concerned about globalization of your project you can change the culture of a single page too

**yourPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page UICulture="pl" Culture="pl-PL" %>
```

If you don't won't this either you can set a **custom dataFormatString** rather than pointing to a standard format string which applies to a cultureSetting.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Would that kill further gloablization of website? By this I mean that even If I had french version of strings in the resources files and someone with french browser would open my website he still would see english version of it?

Comment: I've added some more details which may help you